# Why is Ubuntu 20.04 lts not using the random ipv6 address?

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have a dualstack Internet connection.

In Windows I get ipv6 address from my local DHCPv6 server and 2 other random ipv6 addresses. Wen i check online what ipv6 address windows is using to connect to the internet it is one of the random generated addresses it seems to do this from a security perspective.

Now with Ubuntu 20.04 I setup network in systemd both ipv4 and ipv6 get ip addresses. Just like Windows Ubuntu receives multiple IPv6 addresses but wen i check on internet what ip address is used to the Internet Ubuntu is not using the more secure random IPv6 address but the static IPv6 based on its duid-uuid.

My question is why does it not use the more secure random generated IPv6 to connect to internet websites just as Windows does?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here:
https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/systemd-networkd/

To solve the problem I changed "/etc/systemd/network/99-default.network" to this:

```
[Match]
Name=ens*

[Network]
DHCP=yes
IPv6PrivacyExtensions=true
IPv6AcceptRA=true
```

Thank you @will !

I added the details that solved the problem for me.

Comment: Could you put the details instead of just a link? If the link breaks your answer is no longer useful. Thank you.